# How to make value on axes equidistant?

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I'm working on a project with aChartEngine. I'm facing a problem that value on axes of my chart are not equidistant. It's always auto scale to fit the chart. It looks like this image:

[image]

I looked for solution for this problem on google, stackoverflow and document of aChartEngine http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/index.html, but nothing helps.

So could you please tell me how can I programmatically set value on axes of my chart look like : -2 -1 0 1 2 3...

Comment: The values shown in the picture above **are** equidistant.

Comment: @Rotwang Oh I'm sorry I'm not a native English speaker so I don't know if I have a mistake in grammar here. In this post I mean I want to make the graph's values are : ... -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 ...

Comment: "equidistant" means "having the same distance". I can't understand what do you mean. You can for sure give the X axis an array with the desired values (-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Comment: @Rotwang Yes, what I need here is make both X and Y axis display ... -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 ..... but I don't know how. Could you tell me ?

Comment: It's quite long to explain, but it's in the aChartEngine examples.

Comment: @Rotwang Oh I'm sorry but as I said in my post : "I looked for solution for this problem on google, stackoverflow and document of aChartEngine http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/index.html, but nothing helps". Note that it will always auto set those values to make the chart fit the view.

Comment: Sorry, but I found it hard to believe you couldn't find your way through the online examples. I did successfully. Therefore, it's possible. Just study the official demos.

Comment: @Rotwang thanks for your reply, but I've double checked in demo, and carefully read full source code about XYMultiSeriesRenderer on GitHub but found nothing help for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got my answer. I used mRenderer.setRange(new double[]{-2,2,-2,2}); and now it looks good. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGEMH.png)